# How can i do streaming using front camera i am using adobe flex?

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, air, flash-cs5

I wanted to open front camera of the Motorola XOOM and try to live streaming using the front camera.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 0):

```
Camera.getCamera()
```

Now, if you post a much more detailed and specific question, I can get much more specific on the answer.

;)